Evaluating a limit given the limit of the derivative as $x$ approaches infinity without using L’Hopital’s
I have been asked to evaluate the following limit as a challenge problem in my real analysis class. This was part of a problem set which mainly involved L’Hopital’s rule, but since you can’t use it here, I’m totally stuck. What theorems would I even use?
PROBLEM
Suppose $f: (1,\infty) \mapsto R \ $is differentiable on its domain. Also suppose that the limit of $f’(x)$ as $x $approaches infinity is zero.
Explain how one would find the value of $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Using L'Hopital's rule you will expect the answer is $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$, only if  we also have that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \lvert f(x)\rvert = \infty$.  This is the requirement for us to use L'Hopitals rule; we can only use the rule in the cases of indeterminate limits $\frac{\pm \infty}{\infty}$.  Now let us argue that this is true without using L'Hopital's rule using this extra condition.
The idea is as follows: take $\varepsilon > 0$; we need to find $M > 1$ such that $\left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{x} \right\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $x \geq M$. How to do this? Well, intuitively, you can take $a$ large enough such that for all $x > a$ we have $\lvert f'(x) \rvert < \varepsilon$ due to the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$ that is given. Additionally, if we take $x \gg a$ (very big), then $$\left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{x} \right\rvert \approx \left\lvert \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} \right\rvert = \lvert f'(c) \rvert < \varepsilon,$$ where $a < c < x$, using Lagrange's mean value theorem. Here we also need that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\lvert f(x) \rvert = \infty$ otherwise the approximation $\lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert \approx \lvert f(x) \rvert$ will not hold for very large $x$.
This is the intuitive idea, I hope you can formalize it into a rigorous proof yourself!
Without the extra requirement, so in case $\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x)| \neq \infty$, we have two cases: either $|f(x)|$ is bounded, in which case the limit is easily seen to be 0, or $|f(x)|$ is not bounded, but there exists a sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3 \to \infty$ such that $\lim_n |f(x_n)| = \infty$. In the latter case I believe you can use a similar argument as the one I gave above. Just take $n$ large enough such that $x_n \gg a$.

Nice. From the fact that $\lim f'(x)=0$ exists , can it be stated that there exists $\lim f(x)=L$ , because as x approaches infinity, we meet a horizontal asymptote which makes the derivative approach 0. If we can state this fact, then it can be derived that $$\lim_{x→∞} \frac{f(x)}{x} =0$$ I am not actually very confident about this, hence I'm not writing it as an answer

@Gwen No you cannot state that. The derivative might go to $0$ (curve gets flatter and flatter locally) while the actual value of the curve can do whatever. If you take $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, or $\log(x)$ then you see that $L = \infty$ while still $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$. But $L$ can also not exist, for instance in the case of $f(x) = \log(x) \sin(\log(x))$. Then $f'(x) = \frac{\sin(\log x) + \log x \cos( \log x)}{x}$ so $f'$ goes to $0$ while $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist

Wow. Thanks for the clarification

For $\varepsilon>0$ we  have to find $x_0$ such that ${|f(x)|\over x}<\varepsilon $ for $x>x_0.$ By assumption there is $x_1$ such that $|f'(t)|<{\varepsilon\over 2}$  for $t>x_1.$ For $x>x_1$ there is $x_1<\xi<x$ so that
$${f(x)-f(x_1)\over x-x_1}=f'(\xi)$$ Hence
$${f(x)\over x}=\left (1-{x_1\over x}\right )f'(\xi)+{f(x_1)\over x}$$
Thus
$${|f(x)|\over x}=\left (1-{x_1\over x}\right )|f'(\xi)|+{|f(x_1|\over x}\le |f'(\xi)|+{|f(x_1)|\over x}<{\varepsilon\over 2}+{|f(x_1)|\over x}$$
For $x>{2|f(x_1)|\over \varepsilon}$ the second term is less than ${\varepsilon\over 2}.$ Hence for $x>x_0:=\max\left \{x_1,{2|f(x_1|\over \varepsilon}\right\}$ we get
${|f(x)\over x}<\varepsilon.$
